# How to get file contents from a MultipartHttpServletRequest object?

Tags: java, ajax, iframe, file-upload

I would like to upload a file from the web page using this strategy. i.e. [Ajax file upload tutorial](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html) . It is going all fine, but the issue is on the server side, where I want to open this file and read its contents.
I am using the following signature for the method which is called on the submit of the form.
i.e.

`public @ResponseBody String getFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request)`

Can any body please let me know that how can I extract the contents of the file?

Comment: Can anyone tell me what would be the url that would be mapped to the signature of the method? I am asking this because I want to send more parameters than just the file to be upload and I can not figure out how to do so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MultipartHttpServletRequest extends MultipartRequest, which has methods for accessing the files.

You can do this:

```
MultipartFile file = request.getFile(paramName);
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartRequest.html